# Volume form on unit normal bundle via moving frames

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, fibre-bundles

Let $M$ be an $m$-dimensional Riemannian submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$. Let $B_1$ denote the unit normal bundle of $M$, whose fiber at $p \in M$ is the $(n-1)$-sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ in the the normal space $N_{p}M$ of $M$ at $p$.

**Problem**: Define a differential form $d\sigma$ of degree $n-1$ on $B_{1}$ such that its restriction to a fiber is the volume element of the fiber.

In the literature I have seen the following construction:

Let $F\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ be the orthonormal frame bundle of $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$. Given any orthonormal frame $(e_{1},\dotsc,e_{m+n})$, there is a well-defined dual coframe $(\widetilde{\omega}^{1},\dotsc,\widetilde{\omega}^{m+n})$ and connection forms $\{\widetilde{\omega}^{i}_{j}\}_{i,j=1}^{m+n}$ -- the latter obtained by expanding the differential of each element of the frame in terms of the frame itself. We may thus consider $\widetilde{\omega}^{i}$ and $\widetilde{\omega}^{i}_{j}$ as forms defined on $F\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$.

Let now $B$ denote the subset of $M \times F\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ such that $e_{1},\dotsc,e_{m}$ are tangent to $M$ and $e_{m+1},\dotsc,e_{m+n}$ are normal to $M$. We indicate by $\phi$ the canonical projection $B \to M$ and by $\phi_{1}$ the projection $B \to B_{1}$ given by

$$
\phi_{1}(p,e_{1},\dotsc,e_{m+n})=(p,e_{m+n}).
$$

Finally, define forms $\omega^{i}$ and $\omega^{i}_{j}$ on $B$ by pulling back $\widetilde{\omega}^{i}$ and $\widetilde{\omega}^{i}_{j}$ by the following (projection after inclusion) composition:
$$
B \hookrightarrow M \times F\mathbb{R}^{m+n} \to F\mathbb{R}^{m+n}.
$$

Then, $d\sigma = \omega^{m+n}_{m+1}\wedge \dotsb \wedge \omega^{m+n}_{m+n-1}$.

**Question**: How do you see that $\omega^{m+n}_{m+1}\wedge \dotsb \wedge \omega^{m+n}_{m+n-1} = d\sigma$?

Comment: You only need to check this at that one point of $M$, and we only need to work on one tangent space of the unit sphere.

Comment: The $1$-forms $\omega^{m+k}_{m_j}$, $1 \le k \le n$, comprise the $so(n)$-valued Maurer-Cartan form on $SO(n)$. What you want to figure out is how to get the standard metric on $S^{n-1} = SO(n)/SO(n-1)$ from these forms and, from that, infer what the volume form is.